# Event handling in JavaScript: how should I handle errors from DOM events?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have the following code:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  throw Error("Can't touch this button!");
});
```

Here we throw an exception as soon as the button is clicked. How do we catch it? It is obvious that this pattern does not work

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

try {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    throw Error("Can't touch this button!");
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
```

I wonder in a browser environment what the common ways are to handle errors like this?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905). Why do you throw the error in the event listener? What do you hope to achieve with this?

Comment: It would make more sense to just disable the button so you can't click it.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon sorry I was just trying to make the question as simple as possible. Sure we wouldn't throw an error on purpose but sometimes there is going to be unhandled errors. The idea is that the callback i.e. listener here can throw an exception which we might not be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a browser context you can register a handler for the `error` event on `window`:

```
window.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("custom error handler kicked in");
    return true; // Prevent default error handler
};
```

It is important that this code does not itself trigger an error, or the handler will be called again, and again...